# Calculate database size after convert to Unicode

Tags: oracle, unicode, character-encoding

We want to convert our database (oracle 11g) from this character set: ISO-8859-8

to this character set: AL32UTF8.

The new mode need to support European characters and more.

Those languages can appear in a lot of tables.

I want to get some estimate about the new size of tables\whole database

according to the the current data.

Is there a good way to do that?

Comment: are you changing the nls_semantic too ? i guess it will affect the size, especially when converting to utf8 the semnatic should be char

Comment: right, it will affect on new tables\columns - but my question is mainly on existing objects.

Comment: You asked the same question already here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53031018/oracle-convert-to-al32utf8-tool

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - this is not the same question. I'm trying now to understand how to do it with no tool according to the comments there.

Comment: If you dont have a lot of have data needs utf8 character set ( Persian , Arabic,Russian...) then you don't have to be worry, because those data get affected from character set conversion . If you want to be sure you can create a test database and apply it there

Answer (score 0):

I don't *think* it will change much. I presume your `VARCHAR2` columns are currently defined like `VARCHAR2(30)`, which by default means `VARCHAR2(30 BYTE)`. And that will remain unchanged after the conversion. If you defined them as `VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)`, I'm not sure what would happen. When you define a column with character symantics, I think Oracle reserves as much space as it might need, which is 4 bytes per character for AL32UTF8.

Comment: I doubt that Oracle will make the database just by default 4 times bigger

Comment: But I think that this is only for new tables... what about existing tables? Is the data will take more space? How can I check it?

Comment: Your existing tables are defined with byte semantics (I'm assuming; that's the default), so I don't think they will change.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are so concerned about the size. Perhaps the DB will be a few(!) percent larger, most likely you will not notice any difference.

Anyway, this PL/SQL should give some idea on the size:

```
declare
   iso_size number;
   utf8_size number;

   iso_size_sum number := 0;
   utf8_size_sum number := 0;
begin

   for aCol in (select table_name, column_name from user_tab_cols where data_type = 'VARCHAR') loop

     iso_size.extend;
     utf8_size.extend;
     execute immediate 
     'select sum(LENGTH('||aCol.column_name||')), 
             sum(LENGTHB(convert('||aCol.column_name||', ''AL32UTF8'')))
      from '||aCol.table_name INTO iso_size, utf8_size;
      iso_size_sum := iso_size_sum + iso_size;
      utf8_size_sum := utf8_size_sum + utf8_size ;
   end loop;

   dbms_output.put_line('Current size: '||to_char(iso_size_sum/1024/1024))||' MiByte');
   dbms_output.put_line('Estimated UTF-8 size: '||to_char(utf8_size_sum/1024/1024))||' MiByte');

end;
```

The two numbers should give you an indication(!) how much the database would grow. Note, the data in Oracle are organized in Blocks (typically 8 kiBytes) not bytes.

Due to performance reasons you should run the query only on one representative table not the entire schema.

Comment: Thanks! in that script - why the current is sum of length and utf sum of lengthb?
 I'm concerned about the size because I just want to know if I need to allocate some more disk space for that. which more things need check?

Comment: It does not matter. In a single-byte character set `LENGTHB`, `LENGTHC` and `LENGTH` return all the same.